# Java Spring and Groovy app with @Transactional - injection returns "proxy" instead of required type

Tags: java, spring, groovy, code-injection, transactional

I have added some groovy files to an existing java + spring project.
The project was working (i.e. past the tests).

I added "@Transactional" to one of the groovy methods and the tests broke.
(In order to add @Transactional, I had to change the Annotation on the class from @Service to @Controller, otherwise the @Transactional was ignored - yuck).

I started getting exceptions
 The exceptions varied

1. @Autowired did not find anything - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

   adding @Qualifier("loadTransactions") gave me the same

   @Resource gave BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'loadTransactions' must be of type [net.idt.workflow.LoadTransactions], but was actually of type [$Proxy33] 
   (I find this a better error message then the @Autowired that I always use :-( )

I changed the type to "Object" and the @Resource injection worked (I am a bit annoyed with @Autowired - so I did not bother trying that with Object :-/ )

I then used the following groovy code:
     loadTransactions.metaClass.object.process();
which I feel "stinks", but WORKS.

My question is: how do I get the nice code that I expected i.e.

   loadTransactions.process();
I should not have to know that the @Transactional is using some proxy

Thanks for your help
Shalom Deitch

Comment: Adding 
 proxy-target-class="true" to the tx:annotation-driven tag in application-context.xml got things working


  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"   proxy-target-class="true"/>